# Slow Bulk API Indexing Performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing slow bulk indexing performance. It ingests 800k documents when i try to ingest 800 to 1000 documents per _bulk api request.

I am using Elasticsearch 2.3.2 version. Please find my stats here: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACcjGUyizpBGfqKfquRpGbASdxr3Gnd2UA4

Any pointers on how to improve the elasticsearch bulk api peformance?

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: Added the proper link

Comment: What kind of disks do you have? (ssd, hdd)

Comment: Local (inside) the server or somewhere else? (NAS, SAN) Are these virtual machines or bare-metal?

Comment: HDD is part of machine (bare-metal) . I am not using any Virtual Machines..individual nodes(with 32 GB RAM)

Comment: Do you have any other processes running on those machines? Asking this because what's related to disk performance is just awful: a refresh operation that takes more than 100 seconds and flushes that take 12 seconds.

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `GET /_nodes`?

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACf5fLF_9BhJrZcHdkcuVk5RLUn4ejA41eg (_nodes api output)

Comment: 3 of my nodes has other process running(hadoop) and other 3 data nodes are dedicated to ES. But Flush and Refresh rate in all 6 nodes looks same.

Comment: Do you think only I/O is causing this or even the mapping rules. I  have "shape_data": {
                    "type": "geo_shape",
                    "tree": "quadtree",
                    "precision": "1m"
                }

Comment: Add `index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1` to all your nodes' `elasticsearch.yml` config files and restart the nodes. **Before** restart, though, run `GET /_nodes/stats` and provide the output. The tool you are using for monitoring doesn't show the rejected requests, if any.

Comment: Also, would be useful to see if the logs show anything interesting, like "throttling"

Comment: Nodes Stats before(index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1)  https://www.evernote.com/l/ACdDPL4HRh9PdZrNH7top6tZYug_2czlEmQ . I don't see any ES logs output other than detected master etc. Will update the stats after restart and starting ingestion

Comment: You do have bulk rejections, not many, but still... I'd suggest trying out a smaller bulk batch size. Try with half of what you have now - 400 documents per bulk.

Comment: Also, regarding your mapping. The edgeNGrams filter you have it's using a rather large(ish) `max_gram` - 40 - do you really need that many?

Comment: The business name are normally little long. But i can try reducing it to 20. Also just curious where did you find the rejections?(which field)

Comment: `"thread_pool": {
                "bulk": {
                    "threads": 8,
                    "queue": 0,
                    "active": 0,
                    "rejected": 36,
                    "largest": 8,
                    "completed": 3099
                }` So 3099 bulks were successful, 36 were rejected. Probably because the queue was full, so the node wasn't able to cope with the load you put on it. So reduce the bulk size.

Comment: Found the field for rejections:  "bulk": {
                    "threads": 8,
                    "queue": 0,
                    "active": 0,
                    "rejected": 36,
                    "largest": 8,
                    "completed": 3099
                },

Comment: Sure will reduce the load!

Comment: Also, a proper bulk indexing process should look at the result of the bulk (because it says how many were indexed) and should **react** accordingly. If there were rejections, then wait a bit before sending the next batch.

Comment: Sure, i will fix it!

Comment: Just curious, the bulk rejections are node specific rite?  when you have many nodes in your cluster and a load balancer above these nodes..how do you manage to delay bulk ingest request on specific node when load balancer controls where the bulk request goes?

Comment: The node that receives the bulk request, at network level, will split the operations in the large bulk request according to the routing value for each document and will send these small bulk requests to the nodes that need to process them.

Comment: Great & Well-Understood. thanks

Comment: Did you get the chance to test again, with `index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1` and maximum 400 docs per bulk?

Comment: I tried running in a different env with the setup you suggested and with a smaller data set (2777 docs). https://www.evernote.com/l/ACfFrAufhfBNhIJ5hzQNHkvldVYtn90Ugp0 . 1st Run: 2016-05-12 01:25:49,128 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 47 minutes, 34 seconds and 32 milliseconds (2854032 ms) . <br/> 2nd Run(after max thread count:1): 
2016-05-12 02:22:58,966 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 49 minutes, 36 seconds and 769 milliseconds (2976769 ms) . I will be running in my prod env shortly. Do you suggest any other changes for faster indexing?

Comment: The dataset was so small that there were no refreshes or flushes yet :-): `"refresh": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0
                },
                "flush": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "total_time_in_millis": 0
                },`

Comment: What is this? `org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 47 minutes`

Comment: Do you suggest any other changes for faster indexing or shall i run with the same setup but larger data set?

Comment: Pig is a hadoop scripting language to run map reduce jobs.

Comment: That Pig... ok. And why do you measure the time from Pig? Doesn't sound right. And I really really doubt 47 minutes is ES fault.

Comment: :) I didn't measure the index time time from overall Pig execution time..but from 1068.78ms as said by Elasticsearch HQ plugin here: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACfFrAufhfBNhIJ5hzQNHkvldVYtn90Ugp0. But anyway i have started running for larger data set + 400 docs per bulk request.

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACeUny0GFO5ObZvMOZHM1YFHQwRr6D_7Vx8 , Flush rate performance has improved a lot now. The indexing time and Refresh still shows red

Comment: I think it's too soon to say anything about the new approach performance. Perform some more bulk inserts. Any better results?

Comment: Morning results: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACf9751ESbpCLJV2c6yPzm2iQTUJdr4C5xA (slowly flush rate is getting red too)

Comment: Latest update: https://www.evernote.com/l/ACde8xvHbvFDH6ReMrcd1sDoKaxCb_0dugU   Andrei Stefan, please let me know if you like to suggest any other changes?

Comment: There's something really wrong with your nodes. Out of curiosity which nodes have hadoop on them?

Comment: I have never seen such large values for refresh or flush. There is something really wrong with the setup. Maybe it's the disks or the disks setup in some way, or maybe your disks have other heavy things to do, I don't know. I don't think it's ES to blame here.

Comment: 192.168.1.8 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.6 are hadoop nodes, the disks are not RAID0 configured but RAID10. Not sure if it can give such drop

Comment: Actually i used Ubuntu LVM to add different disks such as sda, sdb, sdc to add one logical volume group..

Comment: Sure Andrei, if you think of any other options let me know. Anyway thanks a lot for helping me out in this..you spent lot of time in this. I appreciate that. Have a Great day!

Comment: I suggest testing this on a single node cluster with a normal machine (no RAID or hadoop running) maybe your dev machine or something (doesn't have to be powerful). Prepare the documents in a json file and use the `_bulk` api to send that file to this ES node and see how it performs: `POST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@your_json_file"`